# Store value in multidimensional array if value is equal to key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store the numbers associated with the music values below

```
Store 2797 in house
Store 2797 in rnb
Store 2797 in hiphop
Store 2829 in house
Store 2829 in trap
Store 2829 in hiphop
```

Into the multidimensional array which is such

```
Array ( 
   [house] => Array ( ) 
   [indie] => Array ( ) 
   [trap] => Array ( ) 
   [trance] => Array ( ) 
   [partybangers] => Array ( ) 
   [charthits] => Array ( ) 
      )
```

Which I would like to result in the following

```
Array ( 
   [house] => Array (2797,2829) 
   [indie] => Array ( ) 
   [trap] => Array (2829) 
   [trance] => Array ( ) 
   [partybangers] => Array ( ) 
   [charthits] => Array ( )
      )
```

Currently i'm attempting to array_push by

```
//Create Multidimensional Array to store each ID into dependent on music value matching $musictypestofetch
$outputmultidimensionalevent = array();
foreach ($musictypestofetch as $musicarray){
    $tempmusicarray = array();
    $outputmultidimensionalevent[$musicarray] = $tempmusicarray;
}   
print_r($outputmultidimensionalevent); //Temporary print out
    foreach ($grabbed as $grab)
    {   
    $holdmusicvalues = array(); //Reset Array
    $grabmusicvalues = mysqli_query($dbhandle_word, "SELECT term.name
    FROM wp_2_term_relationships AS rel
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_term_taxonomy AS tax
    ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_terms as term
    ON tax.term_id = term.term_id
    WHERE rel.object_id = '".$grab."'
    AND tax.taxonomy = 'Music'
    AND term.name != 'nightclub'
    AND term.name != 'bigspender'
    AND term.name != 'average'
    AND term.name != 'cheap'
    AND term.name != 'boosted'
    AND term.name != 'recommended' 
    AND term.name != 'Mon'
    AND term.name != 'Tue'
    AND term.name != 'Wed'
    AND term.name != 'Thu'
    AND term.name != 'Fri'
    AND term.name != 'Sat'
    AND term.name != 'Sun'
    AND term.name != 'central'
    AND term.name != 'north'
    AND term.name != 'east'
    AND term.name != 'south'
    AND term.name != 'west'
    AND term.name != 'events'
    AND term.name != 'gaylesbian'"); //Recommended can be removed once the pass over has been done to boosted in the back end of wordpress and all other functions
        while ($musiceventvalues = mysqli_fetch_array($grabmusicvalues)){
        array_push($holdmusicvalues,$musiceventvalues[0]);
        }
        foreach ($holdmusicvalues as $musictostore){
        echo '<br/>Store ' . $grab . ' in ' . $musictostore;
        array_push($outputmultidimensionalevent[$musictostore],$grab);
        }

    }
```

But so far no luck. Am I missing something massively obvious here, I'm starting to feel a bit stupid?

Thanks in advance for any help on something that should be very simple for me to work out!

Comment: where are your codes? and what is the origin of that input strings?

Comment: `$outputmultidimensionalevent[$music] = $number;`

Comment: What is $musictypestofetch defined ?

Comment: $musictypestofetch is `Array ( [0] => house [1] => indie [2] => trap [3] => trance [4] => partybangers [5] => charthits )`

Comment: Your SQL: `AND term.name != 'nightclub'` etc might be optimized a bit too: `AND term.name NOT IN ('nightclub', 'bigspender', etc)`

Comment: @Tommy You forgot a `[]` there probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a simple way to store and retrive your data inside that multidimensional array:

```
<?php
//Global definition of the array
$categories = array(
    "house" => array(),
    "indie" => array(),
    "trap" => array(),
    "trance" => array(),
    "partybangers" => array(),
);

function push_to_category($category,$value) {
    global $categories;
    array_push($categories[$category], $value);
}

push_to_category("house","2797");

//To retrive data you call $categories[$category][index]
//ex) $categories["house"][0] returns 2797

?>
```

Comment: Dude, a class to manipulate a global var? That's not good practice.

Comment: I'm just trying to help, even if the code provided is not amazing, will work. I'm not an expert. Sorry

Comment: If you change it to a function with `$categories` being a by-reference argument, it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I like [FoxNos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256032/store-value-in-multidimensional-array-if-value-is-equal-to-key#answer-26256906), but not the global, since the global might not be a global in another context (`$categories`might be defined in another function or class).

So this is what I would've done:

```php
$categories = array(.........);

function push_to_category(&$categories, $category, $value) {
  array_push($categories[$category], $value);
}

push_to_category($categories, "house","2797");
```

Since the 1st arg is by-reference, you don't need a global, so you can use it anywhere. Minor improvement.

If you're inside another function or class, and want to `push_to_category` a lot, you could even do this:

```php
class UserController {
  function categoriesAction() {

    $categories = array(.........);
    
    $push_to_category = function($category, $value) use (&$categories) {
      array_push($categories[$category], $value);
    }
    
    $push_to_category("house","2797");

  }
}
```

which makes a local function ([closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) that uses/manipulates a local variable (`$categories`).